# When to use parentheses with javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have a function called `showText()` which copies some text from  form textbox to a paragraph elsewhere. It is called with the following:

```
document.getElementById("mybutton").onclick = showText;
```

It will not work if I add the () to the end of showText, which I understand from reading similar answers here is the only way to call a function.

Later in the script it requires the () to work:

```
window.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
    var keycode = e.keyCode;
    if (keycode == 13) {
        showText();
    }
}, false);
```

I'm not sure what is going on here.

Comment: Functions are objects. Your two examples illustrate assignment of the function vs calling the function.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`showText` returns **the function** `showText`.

`showText()` runs the function `showText` and returns **the result**.

When you attach a function to an event handler like .onclick, it is expecting a `function`.

You can call a function and return the result to an event like this: `document.getElementById("mybutton").onclick = showText();` provided the function itself **returns** a function:

```
function showText() {
    return function () { 
        alert('hello world'); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript functions are first class citizens which means they can be assigned to a variable ... that is what you are doing i the first one ... You are basically setting the onclick to a function of your choice (telling the browser that when this is clicked ... call this function)

By using () you are calling the function ..

I can also do something like this

```
function test() {
  alert('Alert something');
}

var a = test;
a();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a statement like:

```
onclick = showText;
```

the right hand side expression is evaluated and the result assigned to the left hand side. If the identifier `showText` resolves to a function object, a reference to that object is assigned.

If `showText` is followed by a formal parameter list enclosed in brackets, i.e. `showText()`, then the function is called with the supplied parameters and the result is assigned. The formal parameter list can be empty.