# How is the function in my eventlistener able to receive an event without using function parameters?

Tags: javascript, function, input, parameters, addeventlistener

I'm working on a very simple game using vanilla JavaScript and the behavior I'm seeing right now goes against everything I've learned about with functions. I don't understand why `getInput` can be called without the usual parenthesis that you'd use when calling functions. In fact, when I add parenthesis like this: `document.addEventListener("keydown", getInput());`, it doesn't work at all.

So then, how am I able to receive and print the event key without it having been passed as a parameter?

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", getInput);

function getInput() {
    console.log(event.key);
}
```

Comment: Because `window.event` exists... yep, it's not intuitive (and shouldn't be used anyway)

Comment: @CertainPerformance This doesn't explain why I'm able to call the function without parameters in `addeventlistener`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775469/when-to-use-parentheses-with-javascript-function Use `()` only when calling the function. Leave them off to only pass the function.